# Set currency name in magento

Tags: magento, currency

I have a store localized in Romania.
Recently I noticed that most online from Romania have currency as Leu/Lei instead of RON.
I was trying to change that too but probably I'm missing something.

in \magento\lib\Zend\Locale\Data\root.xml it's set like this:

```
<currency type="RON">
    <symbol>RON</symbol>
</currency>
```

and ro.xml (same path) have:

```
<currency type="RON">
    <displayName>leu</displayName>
    <displayName count="one">leu</displayName>
    <displayName count="few">lei</displayName>
    <displayName count="other">lei</displayName>
</currency>
```

I didn't see any other place where currency is set. 
Any clues?

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but did you flush cache and rebuild all indexes?

Comment: Yes. I flushed everything but this is not something I changed. It was running with RON since first install. And I didn't changed the files. I only wonder how to convince magento to use lei instead of ron.

Comment: you can change it in root.xml :) `<currency type="RON">
    <symbol>lei</symbol>
   </currency>` ... ro.xml after `<currency type="RON">` add `<symbol>lei</symbol>` and manually delete var/cache/*